# Desktop application to check a users groups?

Tags: development, 2013

I'd like to write a desktop application to allow me to retrieve all of the groups that a user is in in a SharePoint 2013 environment is in. Unfortunately I don't have any idea where to begin - how could I go about this?

Comment: where should this application be run? on the machine with SharePoint or remote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you will run the application on machine with SharePoint you can use this code

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://basesmc2008"))
 {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {

          SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(name);
          SPGroupCollection groups = user.Groups;

        }
}
```

In other case you can use CSOM or [UserGroup.asmx](http://www.innovawiz.com/get-the-sharepoint-groups-a-user-is-part-of-using-sharepoint-object-model).

Comment: Could you provide an example doing this client side? I'm trying, but coming up short.